# Searching for an int in an array

Tags: arrays, search

I am trying to search for an int value in an array that has random numbers
this is what I have so far:

```
String names[]={"Peter","John","Rudy"};
int number[]=new int[3];
for(int z=0;z<3;z++)
{
    number[z]=(int)(1+Math.random()*200);
}
int option=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("choose and option:\n1.names\n2.sorting according to alphabet\n3.search number\n4.J"));
switch(option)
{
    case 1:
    {
        for(int l=0;l<names.length;l++)
        {
        jTextArea1.append(""+names[l]+"\t"+number[l]+"\n");
        }
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    {
        String temp="";
        for(int ii=0;ii<names.length;ii++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<names.length;j++)
            {
                if(names[ii].compareToIgnoreCase(names[j])<0)
                {
                    temp=names[ii];
                    names[ii]=names[j];
                    names[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int x=0;x<names.length;x++)
        {
            jTextArea1.append(""+names[x]+"\n");
        }
    }
    break;
    case 3:
    {
        boolean found=false;
       int searchvalue=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number?"));
       for(int i=0;i<number.length;i++)
       {
           if(number[i]==searchvalue)

           {

               found=true;
           }
       }
       if(found==true)
       {
           jTextArea1.append("number is found"+"\n");
       }
       else
       {
           jTextArea1.append("number is not found"+"\n");
       }
    }
    break;
    case 4:
    {
        for(int q=0;q<names.length;q++)
        {
            if(names[q].startsWith("J"))
            {
                jTextArea1.append(names[q]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Even when I type the correct answer it gives me the "number is not found" message.I'm dumbfounded on what to do.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try printing the `searchvalue`...is it the same number which you entered?

Comment: Also where is the number array defined?

Comment: This is where using a debugger will be helpful. Although your code could be improved, it's basically fine (I ran a version of it to test.) So throw it into an IDE, set some breakpoints, and check that your variables are what you expect. Is searchvalue what you expect? How about the values of number[]?

Comment: @Nullpointer I've tried that and I've gotten the entered value

Comment: @RenegadeAndy it's defined at the top of the code -

String names[]={"Peter","John","Rudy"};
int number[]=new int[3];
for(int z=0;z<3;z++)
{
    number[z]=(int)(1+Math.random()*200);
}

Comment: Can you please add you complete code?

Comment: @KathyA. Yeah,It is what I expect though I think that there's something wrong with the part - if(found==true) because when I try to check my variables under that nothing shows.

Comment: @Nullpointer I've added the whole code now.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for...

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean found = false;
        int searchvalue;
        int[] lottoNumber = new int[6];  
        lottoNumber[0] = (int) ((56 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        lottoNumber[1] = (int) ((56 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        lottoNumber[2] = (int) ((56 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        lottoNumber[3] = (int) ((56 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        lottoNumber[4] = (int) ((56 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        lottoNumber[5] = (5);
        System.out.print("number?");
        searchvalue = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < lottoNumber.length; i++) {
            if (lottoNumber[i] == searchvalue) {

                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found == true) {
            System.out.print("number is found" + "\n");
        } else {
            System.out.print("number is not found" + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This does not have GUI imports in this by the way.What exactly are you trying to do with this? Can you add the whole code?

Comment: I've added the whole code.It's a school project,We have to manipulate arrays.

Comment: One more question. How do you know the value of each index? Did you write a print statement after putting random numbers in it??

Comment: Yeah I print the numbers first and then check it against the inputted number.

Comment: Im pretty sure the logic is right so i gotta agree with the gentleman who concurred my answer, its gotta be the way your prompting for input

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer above works for me! So the answer is your :

```
 int searchvalue=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number?"));
```

That line is probably causing the problem.

Try adding:

```
System.out.println("The number entered was:"+searchvalue);
```

and then compare it to the number you entered.